# How to get a image from the clipboard in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, clipboard

I'm trying to do this using 2 gems: `win32-clipboard` and `clipboard` but i can't do it.

`win32-clipboard`:

```
include Win32
# I don't know what is this buffer, BM = BMP Images but the '??????' is the problem
Clipboard.data(Clipboard::DIB)[0..5000] # => BMB→O     B   (   ?♣  ?♥  ☺   ♥    →O                   ?  ??   ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ???...
Clipboard.data(Clipboard::BITMAP) #=> FFI::NullPointerError
```

`clipboard`:

```
Clipboard.paste # => ""
```

I would like to get the buffer of the image, a Gosu#Image or RMagick#Image.

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**: Is there a way to get the buffer with C++ and load it in Ruby?

I was doing good, `Clipboard.data(Clipboard::DIB)` return the buffer but without BMP Header and i don't know how to get width and height of the image, however i save the image and then load it with gosu gem(Gosu#Image) like that:

```
buffer = Win32::Clipboard.data(win32::Clipboard::DIB)
File.open("image.bmp", "wb") do |file|
  file.write(buffer)
end
image = Gosu::Image.new("image.bmp")
image.width # => 450
image.height # => 450
```

Problem solved, Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the temp file in the clipboard in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471428/how-to-get-the-temp-file-in-the-clipboard-in-ruby)

Comment: i know that but i'm looking for someone to do this in another way, something like Paint works, thank you.